# ArcGIS 10.5 Spatial Analyst Extract-by-Mask work around?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, spatial-analyst

I have 11 different shapefiles all using NAD27 Lambert Conformal Conic with which I use ArcGIS 10.5 Extract By Mask to extract a chunk of a forest map of the same projection parameters. But each time I extract with these shapefiles, I end up with an extraneous portion of a tif to the lower right of the original shape/tif file that did not exist before hand, that only comes about as a result of the Extract By Mask. It is real. I can see it, I can see the values in it. I can probably fill in the bogus values with 0's. But how to tell ESRI this is happening? How to eliminate this? What is the workaround, so this does not reoccur? The extraneous portions are different.[image: Odd piece of Tif created by Extract By Mask]

Comment: What is the Pixel Type and Pixel depth of the  TIFF? Look in Layer Properties. Also look at the NoData value and the options in Environments..., and Geoprocessing Options

Comment: Have you had any luck fixing this issue? I'm having the same problem.

Comment: Hi Tracy: Welcome to the site. Rather than putting your comment in as an answer, you should upvote the question, that will make it more visible on the site.